# Java Thread working correctly only when using println in run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to implement autoscrolling for small project of mine, where I thought of using a thread for it.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("");
        if(isScrolling) {
            view.getWorkarea().autoScroll(direction);

            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I got this strange bug, where it's only working while I don't remove `System.out.println("")`. If I remove it, autoscrolling stops working. Does anyone know why it's happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Because `println()` is a `synchronized` method. This will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786483/code-not-executed-without-a-print-statement/20786677

Comment: Change your isScrolling to volatile.